# how to install gmp and ntl library for riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc complier

Tags: riscv, gmp, ntl

Hi I want to install ntl library using gmp for riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc complier. Changing the compiler in configure file is not working. Does anybody have any leads on how to install it?

Expected that just changing the C and CXX flags in gmp configure file would suffice to compile the library. It doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone provide any leads on how to install it? I have attached the error which occurred while running configure file [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDosB.png).

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options#index-Cross-compiling